# Display hidden field when option selected

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic form that has fields generated through jquery. I am pulling the values from mysql table. I have a select field with three values. If the third value is selected `Other` I am trying to trigger a `change` event to display a hidden input field. Although I have the function trigger when there is a change in the select field with option value of `3`, there is no results or response. How can I display the hidden field when choosing option with value `3`? [DEMO](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/courses_stat.php)

```
$('select').change(function() {
var option = $(this).val();
showFields(option);
return false;
    });
function showFields(option){ 

    var content = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
        content += '<div id="course_'+i+'"><label>Course # '+i+'</label><br /><label>Course Name:</label> <select id="coursename_'+i+'" name="coursename_'+i+'"><option value="">--- Select ---</option>"'
                <?php
                    $course_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses_selection_list ");
                    $course_query->execute();
                    $data = $course_query->fetchAll();
                    foreach ($data as $row){
                            //dropdown values pulled from database
                       echo 'content += \'<option value="' . $row['course_id'] .'">' . $row['course_name'] . '</option>\';';
                    }

                ?>
        '"';                   

    content += '</select><input type="text" id="#newCourse_'+i+'" name="#newCourse_'+i+'" style="display:none;" /></br></div>';

    $('#coursename_'+i).change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 3)
        $('#newCourse_'+i).show();
    else
        $('#newCourse_'+i).hide();
    });

}
    $('#course_catalog').html(content);

}
});
```

HTML

```
<select name="courses_offered" id="courses_offered">
<option value="default">---Select---</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="course_catalog"></div>
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with `i` in `$('#coursename_'+i).change(function() {` , try giving a class name to all the `coursenames` and access with class name , because `i` is declared in for loop , its getting iterated , it may not give expected results

Comment: @BharathRallapalli Alright made the change to classes but still not seeing the hidden field appear.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle..

Comment: @BharathRallapalli http://jsfiddle.net/QUKwL/

Comment: use  $('#coursename_'+i).on('change',function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `change` event handling like this

```
$(document).on('change',".ddlcss", function(){

            if ($(this).val() == 3)
                $(this).next().show();
            else
                $(this).next().hide();
});
```

its always good to use `on` and `off` to bind events for dynamically created elements

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QUKwL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
                       <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').change(function() {
            var option = $(this).val();
            showFields(option);
            return false;
        });
        function showFields(option) {

            var content = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++) {
                content += '<div id="course_' + i + '"><label>Course # ' + i + '</label><br /><label>Course Name:</label> <select id="coursename_' + i + '" name="coursename_' + i + '" class="ddlcss"><option value="">--- Select ---</option>"'
                content += '<option value="1">Biology</option>'; content += '<option value="2">Calculus</option>'; content += '<option value="3">Other - Not Listed</option>'; '"';

                content += '</select><input type="text" id="#newCourse_' + i + '" name="#newCourse_' + i + '" style="display:none;" /></br></div>';
            }
            $('#course_catalog').html(content);
        }
    });

        $('.ddlcss').live('change',function() {
            if ($(this).val() == 3)
                $(this).next().show();
            else
                $(this).next().hide();
        })

</script>
```

Please do like this.Here I am adding one class with your select tag then add event with the help of Live function.But for live function you must be use latest jquery version.

Comment: Dear Add latest jquery version

Comment: I Used this line but this is temporary <script type="text/javascript" src="http://skylearning.in/Resource/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>